# How to suppress IPv4 checksum errors on virtual terminal?

Tags: command-line, virtual-terminal

(Other terminals like `gnome-terminal` and `ssh`ing have no problem at all.)

Every 10 seconds, an error message (`jme 0000:05:00.5: eth0: IPv4 Checksum error`) constantly appears on the virtual terminal (which can be accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1~6</kbd>), and it annoys me because that makes using programss like `vi` or `w3m` very hard.

How to suppress that message on the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happens due to upgrade of drivers to recent versions and you can  fix it by disabling the checksum checking in your PC for that particular connection.

All you need to do is simply open your terminal and type as follow

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

then disable checksum

```
ethtool --offload eth1 rx off tx off
```

that's it. It will stop giving error messages but this  setting will be lost after restarting of your PC.

you would better make it as [start up script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up).

hope that helps.